# Как сравнить значение числа в ячейке с другим sqlite3 python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, sqlite3

Здраствуйте, мне нужно проверить, равно ли значение в ячейке определённому числу. return возвращает строку `<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x0000027CB7DB64C0>`, но не само число, которое мне нужно

**1 файл:** *(Исполняемый)*

```
from db import Database

if db.check() == 3:
    # что-то делается
```

**2 файл:** *(db.py)*

```
import sqlite3

class Database:
    def __init__(self, db_file):
        self.connection = sqlite3.connect(db_file)
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()

    def check(self):
        with self.connection:
            res = self.cursor.execute('SELECT check_db FROM users WHERE check_id = ?',())
            return res
```

Comment: execute не возвращает данные, надо использовать fetchone()  или fetchall(). Посмотрите образцы в сети

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы не возвращаете результат выборки.

Чтобы вернуть найденные данные, необходимо воспользоваться `fetchall()` чтобы вернуть все результаты, или `fetchone()` для первого результата выборки. Также есть `fetchmany()` и в скобках указываете количество необходимых данных из выборки.

Я использую немного другой способ, не через классы, поэтому на его примере покажу:

```
with sqlite3.connect("db_file.db") as adb:
    cur = adb.cursor()

    def check():
        cur.execute("SELECT check_db FROM users WHERE check_id = 'ваше значение'")
        result = cur.fetchall()
        return result
    
    print(check())
```